# Python 3, Update label in Tkinter from different function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, label

So I'm trying to make a GUI in Tkinter and update a label previously made in the main function, and use a button click to trigger the change. However no matter what I try, including putting a new label on that same grid spot seems to work.

How would I go about this?

```
from tkinter import *

class MyFirstGUI:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        master.title("Login")
        Label(master, text="E-Mail Address:").grid(row=0)
        Label(master, text="Password:").grid(row=1)
        Label(master, text="UserID:").grid(row=2)
        e1 = Entry(master)
        e2 = Entry(master)
        e3 = Entry(master)
        e1.grid(row=0, column=1)
        e2.grid(row=1, column=1)
        e3.grid(row=2, column=1)
        b1 = Button(text ="Login!", command=self.test)
        b1.grid(row=3, column=1)
        Label(master, text="Status: ").grid(row=4, column=0)
        Label(master, text="Boop!").grid(row=5, column=0)   

    def test(self):
        # I want to change the label named Boop in this function when button is pressed.
        # Target word is "Beep!"

root = Tk()
my_gui = MyFirstGUI(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change anything, you have to save the object. In classes you need to give it a name starting with "self.".

```
from tkinter import *

class MyFirstGUI:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        master.title("Login")
        Label(master, text="E-Mail Address:").grid(row=0)
        Label(master, text="Password:").grid(row=1)
        Label(master, text="UserID:").grid(row=2)
        e1 = Entry(master)
        e2 = Entry(master)
        e3 = Entry(master)
        e1.grid(row=0, column=1)
        e2.grid(row=1, column=1)
        e3.grid(row=2, column=1)
        b1 = Button(text ="Login!", command=self.test)
        b1.grid(row=3, column=1)
        Label(master, text="Status: ").grid(row=4, column=0)
        self.mylbl = Label(master, text="Boop!")
        self.mylbl.grid(row=5, column=0)

    def test(self):
        self.mylbl.config(text="Beep!")

root = Tk()
my_gui = MyFirstGUI(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Note that I made the initialization 2 lines instead of one. This is very important if you want to access the object later.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much!